# No shadow under uiview

Tags: ios

Hi I am trying to get a shadow under a UITextField. I have made the followin extension to UIView. But if cuts off half of the ui for TextField.

How do you add shadow underneath a UIView/UITextField?

```
public extension UIView {
    func installShadow() {
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)

        let shadowPath = CGPath(ellipseIn: CGRect(x: self.frame.origin.x,
                                                  y: self.frame.origin.y,
                                                  width: self.frame.size.width,
                                                  height: self.frame.size.height),
                                transform: nil)

        self.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using `CGPath(ellipseIn:` is this intentionally?

Comment: Try with this `self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath`

Comment: You need to show an image of how you ***want*** the result to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues mainly, **1.** Using Frame instead of Bounds, and **2.** Using `CGPath(ellipseIn:` your path will be an ellipse

**Use this code**

```
public extension UIView {
    func installShadow() {
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
        self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
Try these ...

public extension UIView {
    func installShadow() {
let shadowSize : CGFloat = 0.5
layer.clipsToBounds = true
            let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: -shadowSize / 2,
                                                       y: -shadowSize / 2,
                                                       width: subView!.frame.size.width + shadowSize,
                                                       height: subView!.frame.size.height + shadowSize))
            self.layer.masksToBounds = false
            self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
            self.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
            self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
            self.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
}
}
```